# How to list all calls of a function at runtime?

Tags: visual-studio, function, debugging, runtime, call

Is there any way to **list** *(show in VS, write to file)* **all callers** *(objects, functions)* **of a function** while the program is running? Possibly using the debugger?

I need to **record** **all calls** (including callers) **of a function** from the launch of the program to its termination.

**A simple scan** of the source code or the binary **does not do the job** because the program could operate as a server which receives requests to call the desired function.

If Visual Studio does not provide this feature, are there any other solutions to this problem?

Comment: If you ensure the function is never inlined, there might be an API to see the call stack at a point, then you might be able to figure out the caller from the stack

Comment: But if possible I don't want to do this manually.

Comment: You may be able to use the stack pointer to get the return address.  The issue is that function names are removed from release executables.

Comment: Another issue is that the operating system can load your program anywhere in memory, so that the addresses may be different on each invocation of your program.

Comment: It can be a debug release.

Comment: But those addresses need to be resolved to object or function names otherwise it's just too hard to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VS profiler tool also would be helpful for you, you could select the method "CPU sampling".

[image]

After it finished, you could select "Caller/Callee".

[image]

Reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/caller-callee-view

Update:
We can export the report:
[image]

Comment: Can you output those to a file?

Comment: @Shiro, Yes, we can export the report. I edit my answer.

Answer (score 1):

IMO, your best solution is to add logging capabilities.

Find all calls to your function.  Print some kind of information to a log file before the function is called.  This will give you an annotated history of the function calls.

Another idea is to use a documentation tool, like Doxygen, which can print a "caller" and "callee" diagram.  However, this is not during your program's execution.

Comment: The problem lies exactly in the runtime aspect. This way I won't see how the program behaves as a server which receives calls.

Comment: This is true. You could replace the function with a macro (yuck) and log the function name (which is available as a macro, I don't remember what though) of the caller

Comment: Is there a macro that holds the callers name?

Comment: But that is just the name of the called function not the name of the caller.

Comment: @Shiro Exactly. That's why you can wrap the function in a macro: `#define MY_FUNCTION(...) do { logFunctionName(__FUNCTION__); myActualFunction(__VA_ARGS__); } while (0)`

Answer (score 1):

If your program is a .NET application, you can use my [Runtime Flow](https://vlasovstudio.com/runtime-flow/) tool to view all callers of a function while the program is running.

Comment: Great application! :) Thanks for sharing.